# Advance filters in grids / tables for angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, grid

I'm looking for grid which works with AngularJS and has strong and usable filter abilities out of the box.

To be more accurate I like that when user filter on column of type "date" he will be able to choose before/after/between dates, and choose the date from "date picker" widget.
For column with final list of values the grid support multi select filter. For example - if I have column named "colors", I like that the filter will contain "Red","Green", "Blue" with checkboxes, and the user will be able to select the colors to filter.

Currently, I'm looking at ANGULAR-UI-GRID (new NG-GRID) and "Smart Table" and both of them great grids, but I couldn't found such support.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in [Angular Grid](http://www.angulargrid.com). It allows you to build custom filters. In the Angular Grid provided example entitled 'Example Large Data' the column 'skills' very closely matches what you describe.